# GridView command (declared in CommanField) call from external Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to call command "Edit" declared in GridView (by CommandField):

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GVtable_1_2_1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ADStable_1_2_1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No records to show.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fields" HeaderText="Fields" SortExpression="Fields" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" SortExpression="Size" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Owning" HeaderText="Owning SortExpression="Owning" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="ADStable_1_2_1" runat="server" DataFile="D:\Projects\DB_projects.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [Fields], [Size], [Owning] FROM [table_1_2_1]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [table_1_2_1] SET [Fields]=@Fields, [Size]=@Size, [Owning]=@Owning">
```

by using external button:

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // how to point on function in GridView like EditCommand or UpdateCommand etc. typed in .aspx file
}
```

Comment: And what row then would button operate? One might be able to do this but dealing with what row or no row adds extra efforts. How is user selecting row?

Comment: In my case, all of my tables (GridView's) have only one record so Button1_click may have to edit 1st (and only row). However you have point out on important problem that I will find in nearly future. Till then I would like to know the solution for relation betwean the .aspx methods and cs methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems very strange that each GV is to only have one row (but, ok).

And it seems even more strange with only one row, we would bother with a extra button - we will now have two buttons that do the same thing. (but, ok).

However, this will work:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table"
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowEditing="GHotels_RowEditing" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"               />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Dexcripton"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit First Row" 
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClientClick="__doPostBack('GHotels','Edit$0');return false"
            />
```

So, the above button would be the same as hitting the edit button on the first row.

Comment: Nearly, but this is not exactly what I was looking for... maybe becouse it is impossible? I was hope that there is any possibility to call EXACTLY same method which is called by pressing on Edit button (related to CommandField) which has own function with saved way to edit rows. By going your way I have to create my own function realted to OnRowEditing. I guess it is impossible?

Comment: Reason for using only one Button to edit GridView is that I'm trying to create "nice view" without multipple Edit links that maybe will be not used for long time. Ideal way is just to click (or double click) on the GridView row to edit it, but this is too hard for me at this moment to implement it in this way.

Comment: If you have the show edit button, then my example code should work. If  you remove that button, then it does not work. but, now that the goal is "clear". It not really about only having one row, since my posted example DOES work as long as you have a edit button in the GV.  I think a better question might be how can I hide the edit button, or not have the edit button in the row, and say have a double click on a given row to edit that one row? Furthermore, it likly better to roll your own edit - pop a dialog, or simple have a nice layout inside of a div, and display that when clicked.

Comment: In other words, trying to put a square peg in a round hole, or trying to re-purpose the built in edit row is less then ideal. I would create my own row edit, and thus you can then add a double click to the row for editing. Going for coffee (but, I'll post a working GV edit with a row click later today). In mean time, you might want to try somthing like this to edit each row - see this simple working web page - try editing a row. We could easy make each row a double click for this example: http://www.kallal.ca/WebSite11/WebForm2

Comment: By the way... is it possible (somehow) to check how the Edit method in CommandField is constructed?

Comment: That is exactly what my example code does - in fact I hit f12 (browser tools), and took a loo at the generated code for the edit button. As I pointed out, my edit button works, and does edit the first row - not sure why yours does not. but yes, that example button code is the SAME code generated by the edit button when you use browser dev tools to look at the generated button. As I stated, I think in most cases it better to dump the built-in editor for gv, and roll your own (such as my linked example). That way you can control this, and even adopt standard plain jane asp.net buttons for this